# misalignment of tables merged with subfloat

Tags: tables, subfloats, multicolumn

I tried to add a column to my main table by using the 'subfloat' method: I merged my main table with a small tables standing for the new column. 
I obtain the desired merged table, but I do not get the alignment of the borders of my second table with the borders of my main table. 
Any help on that issue or any different solution to obtain the desired final table with borders aligned?

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\centering
\captionsetup[subfloat]{labelformat=empty}
\subfloat[]{%
\begin{tabular}{|r}
   \hline
       & \\
       & \\
       & \\
       & \rotatebox{90}{\parbox{2mm}{\multirow{2}{*}{1990}}} \\
       & \\
       & \\
       \hline
  \end{tabular}}
\subfloat[]{%
\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{2cm}{\textbf{Clusters}} &
    \multicolumn{9}{c|}{\textbf{2015}} \\
    %\hline
    \cline{2-10}
    & \textbf{SOM 1} & \textbf{SOM 2} & \textbf{SOM 3} & \textbf{SOM 4} & \textbf{SOM 5} & \textbf{SOM 6} & \textbf{SOM 7} & \textbf{SOM 8} & \textbf{SOM 9} \\
    %\hhline{~--}
    \hline
    \textbf{SOM 1} &  & & & & & & & & \\
    \hline
    \textbf{SOM 2} & &&&&&&&  & \\
    \hline
    \textbf{SOM 3} & &&&&&&&& \\
    \hline
    \textbf{SOM 4} & &&&&&&&& \\
    \hline
    \textbf{SOM 5} & &&&&&&&& \\
    \hline
    \textbf{SOM 6} & &&&&&&&&  \\
    \hline
    \textbf{SOM 7} & &&&&&&&& \\
    \hline
    \textbf{SOM 8} & &&&&&&&& \\
    \hline
    \textbf{SOM 9} & &&&&&&&& \\
\hline
   \end{tabular}}
   \caption{Countries evolution in the clusters from 1990 to 2015 \label{tab countries2}}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: Welcome to TEXSE, could you make your script compilable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use `subfloat` for such purposes. Desired goal is simpler to achieve in single table:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array, makecell, multirow}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\rotheadgape{}
\usepackage{lscape}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont 1990 }
\begin{tabular}{|c|>{\bfseries}c|*{9}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}}
    \hline
\multicolumn{2}{\multirow{2.4}{*}{Clusters}}
        &   \multicolumn{9}{c|}{\textbf{2015}} \\
    \cline{3-11}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}
        & \thead{SOM 1} & \thead{SOM 2} & \thead{SOM 3} & \thead{SOM 4}
        & \thead{SOM 5} & \thead{SOM 6} & \thead{SOM 7} & \thead{SOM 8}
        & \thead{SOM 9} \\
    \hline
\multirow{9}{*}{\rothead{1990}}
    & SOM 1 &&&& &&&& & \\
    \cline{2-11}
    & SOM 2 &&&& &&&& & \\
    \cline{2-11}
    & SOM 3 &&&& &&&& & \\
    \cline{2-11}
    & SOM 4 &&&& &&&& & \\
    \cline{2-11}
    & SOM 5 &&&& &&&& & \\
    \cline{2-11}
    & SOM 6 &&&& &&&& & \\
    \cline{2-11}
    & SOM 7 &&&& &&&& & \\
    \cline{2-11}
    & SOM 8 &&&& &&&& & \\
    \cline{2-11}
    & SOM 9 &&&& &&&& & \\
\hline
   \end{tabular}
   \caption{Countries evolution in the clusters from 1990 to 2015 \label{tab countries2}}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, yes your solution fits better! I'll be using it, many thanks, once again.

Comment: I've just used your code, it works pretty fine, but the table does not fit the page (it is cut at SOM 7), even if we use landscape mode. It seems that the landscape mode does not work properly, since the table is displayed in portray mode... any suggestion to fix this issue? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @AnnaNovaresio, you not given any information about your document pages layout. In my MWE it fit a page well. Until you will not provide missing information I'm not able to suggest you what to do. Also the contents of cells are unknown. With use of the `pdflscape` package pdf viewer rotate landscape package (to help you for easy read them), however printing this page is correct. If you not like this, instead `pdflscape` use `lscape` package.

Comment: yes sorry, my document pages layout is the following:  \documentclass[12pt, a4paper, titlepage]{article}. I tried to use also lscape package, but the table does not fit anyway.

Comment: @AnnaNovaresio, your claim not hold. I edit my answer where I consider your preamble and add some dummy text by which You can see that table is narrower than text. Of course this is valid any for given contents of cells. If you have different (wider) contents, than table can be wider. However, this information you didn't provided so far.

Comment: @Zarco, I tried your edited code and now it works. Many thanks!

Comment: @AnnaNovaresio, well, my code worked from very beginning ;-). Since it seems that answer is useful to you,  you can accept it (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answer). Happy TeXing!

Comment: @Zarco I achieve the result when I use the lscape environment (2nd version), not pdflscape (1st version), but anyway, fine, many thanks! ;-)

Comment: @Anna88, both packages gives the very same reuslt, Difference is that "`pdflscape` adds PDF support to the landscape environment of package lscape, by setting the PDF /Rotate page attribute. Pages with this attribute will be displayed in landscape orientation by conforming PDF viewers" (from CTAN). With other words: with `pdflscape` pdf viewer rotate presented page for easy reading of page contents on your screen. However, at printing you need to set printer to "auto portrait/landscape" option for correct printing.